# Set Cron job for opening a jsp page periodically?

Tags: java, jsp, cron, jobs

I am creating an application in JSP to get me email notification periodically. I have written code for that in a JSP. So i want to open my jsp page at a preset intervals using **cron jobs**.

I have searched a lot to get how to put cron job for jsp page. In all YouTube videos every one is showing how to schedule the task. No one is showing the core page. ie. how should be the page that is written the code for that.

Can anybody give a reference page or a sample video how should be a cron job page and how could i schedule the JSP page in cron job.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: So you want to trigger an event from the browser(client)?

Comment: why do you want to load jsp periodically ?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I totally misunderstand this question, you want to *load* a web page implemented as a JSP ... periodically.

To do this:

1. Figure out to *load* the web page using a command line tool such as `wget` or `curl`.  These commands send an HTTP request to a URL and then capture the output.  The respective `man` entries explain how to do it.
2. Turn the (typically) one-line command to load the web page into a `cron` job.  That is also trivial if you know how to write a cron job, and there are numerous tutorials on how to do it.  Or you could read the `man` entry.

As you can see, it is irrelevant what the web page is implemented in.

---

If you mean something else, please update your Question to clarify it.